# Problem importing a dashboard: The response shows a login page

Tags: apache-superset

When I use the Superset's API to import a dashboard the response shows me a login page.

I am doing the request using Python.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}', 
    'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
    'Referer': url
}
files = { 
    'formData': (
        dashboard_path, 
        open(dashboard_path, 'rb'), 
        'application/json'
    )
}

response = requests.get(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble with the Superset API myself, mostly because I did not handle the CSRF Token correctly:

It seems to be important that the retrieval of the JWT Token, the CSRF Token and the actual request happen in the same session.

If I don't do that, I can reproduce your error and are also sent to the login page (also you use a GET request in this example, but it should be POST).

Here an example from my local test-setup:

```py
import requests

session = requests.session()

jwt_token = session.post(
    url='http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/login',
    json={
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "refresh": False,
    "provider": "db"
    }
).json()["access_token"]

csrf_token = session.get(
    url='http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/csrf_token/',
    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}',
    }
).json()["result"]

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
}

response = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/dashboard/import',
    headers=headers,
    files={
        "formData": ('dashboards.json', open("dashboards.json", "rb"), 'application/json')
    },
)

session.close()
```